# Advancing the clock of a CMOS IC with multiple signals

Tags: clock, cmos, trigger

[image]

What would be the best way to advance the clock of a CMOS OC from multiple signals?

In my situation the "upper" signal puts the system in working and the system itself generate the next clock pulse to advance and the original signal, the "upper" remains active throughout the whole time.

Would a capacitor trigger construction work?

[image]

I tried with the Falstad simulator.  It seems to work, but after manipulating both switches it stops working and the capacitors seam to hold charge.

These trigger signals are about 1 ms in time.

The CD4022 always returns to pin 1 after reset.

Do you need some sort of transistor trick to cut off the starting signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to discharge the capacitor when the switch is off, without compromising the other switch input. A 10 kΩ 'pull-down' resistor from the left side of each capacitor to ground should do it.

Note that this will cause the output voltage to pulse *negative* when the switch is opened. The CD4022 has input protection circuits which can be damaged by voltage below -0.5 V and current higher than 10 mA. The 10k pull-down resistors limit the injected current to ~1 mA, so it should be safe.